# How can add blank as a first element of a dropdown in sharepoint list using JSON list formatting?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a dropdown column of type lookup. I want to add a blank as a first element in this dropdown.
Can I do this using JSON list Formatting in sharepoint?

I tried this code but not working:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
            "forEach": "person in @currentField",
            "txtContent": "=if(loopIndex('person') == 0, 'test', person)"         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, lookup column get values from parent list, adding a blank value as a first element in this lookup column dropdown is not available.